# JBoss WildFly + Status Code 302

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

When I deploy my Java application to JBoss WildFly 10 (drop `.war` into deployments folder), then later attempt to access my war webservices via a client, I always get a status code **302**.

However, if I deploy the same application via the Eclipse IDE (Run-->Run on Server) on the same JBoss WildFly, then later access my war webservices, everything works fine and successfully.

Does anyone know why this is, and how I can correct it?

Comment: 302 - Found/Moved Temporarily. Most often occurs when you try access resource via **https** when there only **http** or vice versa, so you receive 302 code and new url in response. Did you try to access your web servuce by this url?

Comment: @Rustam I'm always accessing the service utilizing the same client. The only thing that is changed is how the war file is deployed. The client is accessing the service using the URL http://localhost:8080 ...

Comment: IDE deploying may differ with manual, so check url that you get with 302 code

Comment: I've checked the manuals, simply says to drop the war file within the deployment directory.

Comment: Can Anyone assist?

Comment: The project exposes some web services. The project works absolutely fine on wildfly 10, but only if I deploy it within eclipse (run--> run on server). The project (war) also  works fine when deployed on Glassfish 3.x, 4.x and even IBM Liberty. 
The only situation where the project does not work is if I deploy the .war (copy the .war and drop it into standalone/deployments directory) on Jboss Wildfly 10.  If I deploy the .war this way, or alternatively, add the deployment from the console, then attempt to access any of my web services via a test client, JBoss returns a status 302 (a redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Likely your browser is returning a result from it's local cache.  302 Founds are redirects, but not always path or protocol redirects; the browser can give a 302 too if it finds the resource you asked for on disk instead of going to the web server to go get it.  Unless otherwise instructed by the server, browsers will aggressively cache whatever it can.  If you're just dev testing, you can do a hard refresh (e.g. most browsers Shift-F5) or explicitly disabling caching when testing (Chrome/Edge Dev Console -> Network Tab -> Click "Disable Cache").  On your local you might have a rule not to cache from localhost or Eclipse might be clearing the cache for you.

If you confirm the issue is caching, you'll want your server to tell clients that it's not OK to indefinitely cache. Review [MDN's Cache Control Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#directives)
to review available caching directives.  You have lots of options here.  Consider what changes in your app, and what kind of a burden not caching will put on the server and clients.  I recently went through this with an Electron app.  It has a buildchain that names most files based on a hash of their contents, so most files can be cached indefinitely because the name will change if the contents change.  The index.html file was the one file that, if cached, caused problems, so I had to attack that.  You might also have java code serving your pages?  If so you can set your cache-control response headers from there.

If you want the Jboss/Wildfly server to set response headers for you, or you need to enact cache controls on static resources that change content but not name when you update them, then you can set up a filter to do that for you.  From the console, add a response header filter under config->subsystems->undertow->filters->view->response header.  Choose cache-control and fill out per the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#directives).  Then, under config->undertow->servers->(your server)->hosts->(your host)->filters, add the filter to the host.  You'll have to define a predicate as described [here](https://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-2.0.0/predicates-attributes-handlers.html).  You can start with this predicate as an example, which matches anything deployed to the /static path:

```
path-prefix('/static')
```

After you make the change, you'll need to flush or disable the cache so that the browser talks to the server one more time and gets the new cache control header.  You can confirm with dev tools both the response header comes, and subsequent calls to resources get a 200 or a 304 (not modified, in the case of a no-cache directive)